# Experience with other EC2 kernels

Tags: amazon-ec2, kernel

I'm curious if any of you have used any of the non-amazon-provided EC2 kernels with success?   Canonical seems to provide newer kernels (2.6.28, eg), but there are some mixed reviews about their successful usage on the EC2 hardware.

I'm mainly interested in newer versions, not necessarily 2.6.18 stuff from other vendors (unless there is a smart reason to be using it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 2.6.27 from Canonical.  In general it is pretty good, but it has a [nasty bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/276476) that causes some instances to freeze sometimes.

Comment: Have you experienced the freezes?  Do they happen at first start or randomly?  How often do they happen?

Comment: Yes, they have happened to me.  They are random.  The machine usually goes weeks before freezing.

Answer (score 0):

We're moving some of servers from Xen to EC2. I'm using a xen kernel and everything works. But we haven't 'put it through it's paces', so I'm not sure if it works well / badly. :)

Comment: But which xen kernel?  The older stock ones work great, I'm interested in some of the newer ones.